# How do I define a type as a vector of another defined type?

Tags: julia

So what I want to do is something like: Define a type Point that is constructed from floats passed by the user. This is supposed to store the coordinates of a point.
struct Point
x::Float64
y::Float64
end
This works well enough.

Now, I want to define a line segment that is defined as a vector of Point types which accepts two points from the user and creates a vector of 1000 points in between and assigns it to the line and constructs it.
'''
s=Point(1,1)
t=Point(8,9)

```
struct Line::Vector{Point}
    s::Point
    t::Point
    Line(s,t)=new([Point(s.x+i*(t.x-s.x)/1000,s.y+i*(t.y-s.y)/1000) for i=0:1000])
end
```

'''
I can't quite get it to work, trying variations of the code above. Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

In some implementations you will want your `Line` to behave as an actual `Vector` in that case you need to inherit on the `AbstractVector` type:

```
struct Point 
  x::Float64
  y::Float64
end

struct Line <: AbstractVector{Point}
  s::Point
  t::Point
  points::Vector{Point}
  Line(s::Point,t::Point) = 
    new(s,t,Point.(range(s.x,t.x,length=100),range(s.y,t.y,length=100)))
end

Base.size(line::Line) = (length(line.points), )
Base.getindex(line::Line, ix) = line.points[ix]
```

I have slighlty shortened the code to generate points.
Moreover, you can see this required defining some basic methods (you might also want to add `setindex` if you want to mutate the `Vector`).

Now let us see how it works and how `Line` behaves as a `Vector`:

```
julia> line = Line(Point(0,1), Point(1,3));
100-element Line:
 Point(0.0, 1.0)
 Point(0.010101010101010102, 1.02020202020202)
 Point(0.020202020202020204, 1.0404040404040404)
 ⋮
 Point(0.9797979797979798, 2.95959595959596)
 Point(0.98989898989899, 2.9797979797979797)
 Point(1.0, 3.0)

julia> line[1], line[2], line[end]
(Point(0.0, 1.0), Point(0.010101010101010102, 1.02020202020202), Point(1.0, 3.0))
```

With this implementation `first` and `last` work as well (similarly to the other answer) so you might consider removing `s` and `t` from the struct (depends on your code):

```
julia> first(line), last(line)
(Point(0.0, 1.0), Point(1.0, 3.0))
```

Comment: Ah yeah, using the `AbstractVector` interface is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually simpler than you might think!

```
struct Point
    x::Float64
    y::Float64
end

struct Line
    points::Vector{Point}
end

Line(s::Point, t::Point) = Line([Point(s.x+i*(t.x-s.x)/1000,s.y+i*(t.y-s.y)/1000) for i=0:1000]) # Aside: this is a function. You could also define it as a long-form function.
```

Then, for example

```
julia> s = Point(1,1)
Point(1.0, 1.0)

julia> t = Point(8,9)
Point(8.0, 9.0)

julia> Line(s,t)
Line(Point[Point(1.0, 1.0), Point(1.007, 1.008), Point(1.014, 1.016), Point(1.021, 1.024), Point(1.028, 1.032), Point(1.035, 1.04), Point(1.042, 1.048), Point(1.049, 1.056), Point(1.056, 1.064), Point(1.063, 1.072)  …  Point(7.937, 8.928), Point(7.944, 8.936), Point(7.951, 8.943999999999999), Point(7.958, 8.952), Point(7.965, 8.96), Point(7.972, 8.968), Point(7.979, 8.975999999999999), Point(7.986, 8.984), Point(7.993, 8.992), Point(8.0, 9.0)])
```

If you want to get the s and t back, then you can just grab them from the array of points. In fact, one "Julian" way to do this would be just to use multiple dispatch and add methods for the `Line` type to `first` and `last`, e.g.

```
julia> import Base.first

julia> first(l::Line) = first(l.points)
first (generic function with 42 methods)

julia> import Base.last

julia> last(l::Line) = last(l.points)
last (generic function with 36 methods)

julia> first(l)
Point(1.0, 1.0)

julia> last(l)
Point(8.0, 9.0)
```

Now if you want to make this more general, to allow points of any type rather than just `Float64`, then you could simply write

```
struct Point{T}
    x::T
    y::T
end

struct Line{T}
    points::Vector{Point{T}}
end
```

instead, to make these structs parametric.